# Using ajax request in Django without form element

Tags: ajax, django, decorator

I'd like to send an ajax request (via Jquery, although I think that's irrelevant in this situation) without using a form element in Django. According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#page-uses-ajax-without-any-html-form), I should be able to do that by using the `ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator, however, I get `Error was: cannot import name ensure_csrf_cookie`.

I'm using the following import `from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie`.

I didn't find a great deal of documentation about `ensure_csrf_cookie`, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

By the way, using `@csrf_exempt` works as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ensure_csrf_cookie` may only be a 1.4 alpha feature if you're having trouble importing it -- I can import it just fine with the same statement on trunk.

The simplest solution here is to pass the csrf_token VALUE in the ajax call itself.

You said you were using jQuery.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
             csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' // just the token value
        },
        success: function(response) {
        }
    })
```

It appears this `ensure_csrf_cookie` forces the view to set the csrf cookie that would be required for use in the automatic cookie based csrf protection mechanism for jquery ajax calls described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: I didn't know 'ensure_csrf_cookie' is a 1.4 alpha feauture. That's why I'm getting Import error (I'm running 1.3). As for your suggestion, my javascript is not embedded in my template, so {{ csrf_token }} is not going to be replace for the actual token. Do you have a workaround about this?

Comment: Yes, implement the jQuery function here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax where a cookie is placed on the client browser with the csrf_token. It should work in most cases without this new 1.4 feature?

Comment: Great. I was a bit hesitant to use that approach because it looked ugly but works great. By the way, should I avoid using 'csrf_exempt' whenever I can or there are also drawbacks (security-wise) of using ensure_csrf_cookie or the option you just suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You're right - this appears to be a bug in the documentation. You should be able to use [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) instead (same documentation page).

Comment: If ensure_csrf_cookie is a 1.4 alpha feature (as suggested by Yuji), then the documentation just need to clarify this. Yes, csrf_except works but ensure_csrf_cookie looked as a better tool for this job.

Comment: Yeah, it's not in the docs for 1.3: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#page-uses-ajax-without-any-html-form

Comment: Indeed. /dev/ vs /1.3/. I should be more carefully about that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Yuji works perfectly if you have access to the Django tag. If in your page, you already have a form that is using the tag (thus it has the hidden input field containing the CSRF) you can use:

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val());

    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        success: function() {
            ...
        },
```