# django does not send csrf token again after browser cookies has been cleared

Tags: django, cookies

In normal situation, django will send csrf token via cookie which can be used by ajax post method later. However when I clear cookies in the browser(Chrome or Firefox), the csrf token is not sent to browser anymore, the session id is still sending but no csrf token. Does anyone know what's going wrong?

I solved this issue by adding  {% csrf_token %} to my template and the SET-COOKIE header appears along with that page request. it turns out that you have to put the {%csrf-token%} in the template in order to make the server send the token via SET-COOKIE header

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at `django/middleware/csrf.py` in which `CsrfViewMiddleware` class is declared. As you can see in `def process_response(self, request, response)` there are three conditions that prevent cookie setup:

```
def process_response(self, request, response):
    if getattr(response, 'csrf_processing_done', False):
        return response

    # If CSRF_COOKIE is unset, then CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view was
    # never called, probaby because a request middleware returned a response
    # (for example, contrib.auth redirecting to a login page).
    if request.META.get("CSRF_COOKIE") is None:
        return response

    if not request.META.get("CSRF_COOKIE_USED", False):
        return response

    # Set the CSRF cookie even if it's already set, so we renew
    # the expiry timer.
    response.set_cookie(settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME,
                        request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"],
                        max_age = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 52,
                        domain=settings.CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                        path=settings.CSRF_COOKIE_PATH,
                        secure=settings.CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE
                        )
    # Content varies with the CSRF cookie, so set the Vary header.
    patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
    response.csrf_processing_done = True
    return response
```

Check which is applied for you.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. After debugging against django source, the reason is:

> If your view is not rendering a template containing the csrf_token
>   template tag, Django might not set the CSRF token cookie.

Two solutions:

- Add `{% csrf_token %}` in your template
- Use `@ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator for your view

For detail your can refer [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: nearly broke my head trying to figure out why am getting "CSRF token missing or incorrect." after first successful login. @ensure_csrf_cookie solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was VSCode debugger. 
I turned on server via VSCode debug mode, then open new incognito window (obviously there were no cookies), and django stopped setting missing cookie. 
When I started server as normal, the problem has gone.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer is useful nowadays, but not 7 years ago...

Answer (score 0):

In most cases issue caused by second check mentioned in a previous answer

```
if not request.META.get("CSRF_COOKIE_USED", False):
        return response
```

This can be solved by using [@ensure_csrf_cookie](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) decorator for the view. If used - check is passed and cookie is set/renewed each time view is rendered.

See also related topic: [Using ajax request in Django without form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018230/using-ajax-request-in-django-without-form-element)