# Jquery Ajax DataType 'html is not defined'

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post

I am trying to get my jquery ajax working properly, but facing a `ReferenceError` when developing with Firebug:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.my-div').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:href,
      dataType:html,
      success: function(data, status, xhr){ $('#div_to_load_html').html(data); },
      error: function(){ alert("Error"); },
    });
    });
})
```

html:

```
<div class='my-div'><a href='/place/to/go/'>GO!</a></div>
```

When I click 'my-div', Firebug returns: ReferenceError: html is not defined @ http://www.mydomain.com/:38, which references the line from my jquery `dataType:html`.

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just remove the option "`dataType:html`," to let `$.ajax` deduce the datatype.

But, to answer the question, the right syntax id `dataType:'html'` with quote because it is not a variable

Comment: Thanks so much for the first answer. Any idea why I am getting a `403 forbidden` error in Firebug? I am new to ajax techniques, and I appreciate the advice...  I will accept your answer when time limit expires.  Thanks!

Comment: Could be a "cross domain" restriction : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I figured it out. Using django framework one must insure that `csrf_token` accompanies post data. Anyone else having same issue should check [This SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018230/using-ajax-request-in-django-without-form-element) and use either `ensure_csrf_cookie` or add `csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'` to their jquery `data`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a string: `dataType:'html',`

Comment: Thank you for the answer @shaun5. Unfortunately I believe Bouillou answered first.  Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

this

> dataType:html,

line should be corrected as

> dataType:'html',

you have to necessarily use this line in some browsers like firefox. Unless you will get an error where you attach the result into the page.