# how do I use ensure_csrf_cookie?

Tags: python, django, django-views, csrf

I'm new to python. Also new to Django. I'm trying to make an AJAX request and followed the instructions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie). at first, the result of retrieving the csrf cookie was always null, so I found a decorator method called ensure_csrf_cookie. The problem is it asks for a view, and I've no idea what view to pass and where I can get a reference to it. The code is quite simple:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

def csv_to_xform(csv, template):
    return render_to_response(template, { "data": "it works!" })
```

Do I need to use a class based view? if so, is there a better way to set the cookie? I'd like not to use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019168/1029988), because I don't want to have to manually handle the value.

The rest of the code is as follows:

sandbox.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sandbox</title>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/csrf.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#send-csv-btn').click(function () {
                    $.post('/csv', { 
                        data: '1, 2, 3',
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.debug(response);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            console.debug(response);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="button" id="send-csv-btn" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'dkobo.formbuilder.views.main', name='fb'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^csv$', 'dkobo.formbuilder.views.csv_to_xform', { "template": "sandbox-stub.html" }),
    url(r'^sandbox$', 'dkobo.formbuilder.views.sandbox')
)
```

settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cookies sets on server response, so you need to setup @ensure_csrf_cookie decorator for view, that renders page, from which user will make ajax-request.

On example, if users browser make ajax-request on sites main page, set this decorator for view, responsible for main page.

**UPDATE:** ajax request calls from sandbox page?
then try to set ensure_csrf_cookie for sandbox view, like this:

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def sandbox(request):
...
```

Comment: I uploaded the rest of the code... could you give an example?

Comment: Plus "from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie"

Answer (score 29):

For those looking for a way to do this with class based view:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

class MyView(View):

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       ...
```

Comment: Via the docs, I think you're supposed to decorate `dispatch()` instead. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class .  Also, you can just add the decorator right above the class declaration instead, I think it's a bit cleaner.  e.g.   `@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie, name='dispatch')`

Comment: This works great with `rest_framework` but where I struggle is the authentication. So from django I render a template having some js code and using axios `axios.post('/post/..', form_data, {headers: {"X-CSRFTOKEN": csrftoken}})`. My view class is protected with `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )`. Problem is user is still anonymous and I get an Unauthorized as response.

Answer (score 3):

Although you have found what you were looking for these concepts will help you.

Views are functions that get called when a URL is requested. And there are two types of views:

1. Function based views
2. Class based views.

The basic working of view is to process a HttpRequest and send out a HttpResponse. 
And every view that is returning a HttpResponse must have a request parameter.

Ex of a function based view:

```
def myView(request):
   ...
  # process the request here
   return HttpResponse() # or render_to_response depending upon what you want.
```

I dont see a `request` parameter in your view.

Now a decorator is something that puts certain conditions on a view.

For example: If you have view function for commenting and you want the user to be logged in to comment, then you can use a `login_required` decorator on the view.

This will ensure that anyone who wants to comment will first need to login. The basic syntax is:

```
@login_required   # this is the decorator
def comment(request):   # this is the view on which the decorator is acting upon
 ...
 ... 
 return HttpResponse()
```

Similar to the @login_required, @ensure_csrf_cookie is a decorator.

Comment: aahhh now I get it! I knew the part about views and just found out the first argument passed is the request object. I didn't know that decorators were different from normal functions. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: where do i put it on a class-based view?  e.g. DRF's `HyperLinkedModelViewSet`?

Answer (score 2):

CSRF tokens are automatically validated when you have:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
...
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
...
)
```

in your project `settings.py` file.

When you have such middleware, you need only to put crsf_token variable to all your forms (in templates), and it's automatically validated, for example:

```
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
...
```

I don't know if I understood your problem at all ;)

Comment: according to what I understood, the `{% csrf_token %}` element needs to be inside a form. I might not have a form on my template (in this case I do, but it's the sandbox). I basically want to be able to set the cookie without a form element

Comment: I tried what you say, and it didn't work. `{% csrf_token %}` returns nothing. I'm updating the post to include the rest of the relevant code.